# Add a reminder in outlook for every third business day of the month using vba or otherwise

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Can someone please help me in adding a reminder in outlook 2010 for every third business day of the month using vba or otherwise. I have tried it in MS outlook 2010 only but no success.

I only want the working day (not a holiday nor a weekend) to be set as reminder date. Outlook select the weekends too, which is an issue!

Comment: If you use a reoccurring appointment reminder, you can set it for the third weekday of each month.

Comment: @bobSmith1432, can you explain how?

Comment: @bobSmith1432 I actually want to set the reminder for every third working day of the month. The recurring reminder wont work if its an holiday(NYSE closed).

Comment: This is not something Outlook has a native tool for. Maybe [take a look at this](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/create-appointments-workday/) to see if it might help in your case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this VBa which I've written for you... Please note, I'm in the UK so used UK date format. The code below isn't designed to be totally perfect for your needs (although it does do what you want), but it gives you a starting point too so you can tweak as you need.

```
Sub CreateEvent() 

 ' ====================     UPDATE THE DATES BELOW and add all the public holidays
    Dim publicHolidayDates(0 To 1) As Date
    publicHolidayDates(0) = "5 / 5 / 2014" ' this is used for demo purposes. The third working day of May is 5th - I've pretended 5th is bank holiday and as such, the event is entered on the 6th
    publicHolidayDates(1) = "01/01/2015"    

    Dim checking As Boolean
    checking = True

    ' ====================    ENTER THE STARTING DATE
    Dim myDate As Date
    myDate = "1 / 5 / 2014"

    Dim dayToCheck As String

    Dim dayResult As Integer

    Dim thirdDayYet As Integer
    thirdDayYet = 0

    Dim thirdMonthYet As Integer
    thirdMonthYet = 0

    ' ====================     How many months into the future do you want to add it too (start with 1 just to see it add it to next month)?
    Dim numberOfMonthsToAddReminderToo As Integer
    numberOfMonthsToAddReminderToo = 2

    Do While (checking)

        dayToCheck = Format(myDate, "dddd")

        If (LCase(dayToCheck) <> "saturday" And LCase(dayToCheck) <> "sunday") Then

            Dim canContinue As Boolean
            canContinue = True
            For i = 0 To UBound(publicHolidayDates)
                If publicHolidayDates(i) = myDate Then
                    canContinue = False
                    Exit For
                End If

            Next i
            If (canContinue = True) Then
                thirdDayYet = thirdDayYet + 1
            End If
        End If

        If (thirdDayYet = 3) Then
            SaveToCalender(myDate)
            thirdMonthYet = thirdMonthYet + 1
            thirdDayYet = 0
            myDate = "01/" & month(myDate) & "/" & Year(myDate)
            myDate = DateAdd("m", 1, myDate)
        End If

        If (thirdMonthYet = numberOfMonthsToAddReminderToo) Then
            checking = False
        End If

        myDate = DateAdd("d", 1, myDate)

    Loop

End Sub

Sub SaveToCalender(ByVal myDate As Date)

    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim oNameSpace As NameSpace
    Dim oItem As AppointmentItem

    On Error Resume Next
    ' check if Outlook is running
    oApp = GetObject("Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        'if not running, start it
        oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

    oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    oItem = oApp.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    ' ====================     UPDATE THE DETAILS BELOW with the appointment details
    With oItem

        .Subject = "This is the subject"
        .Start = myDate & " 09:00:00"
        .Duration = "01:00"

        .AllDayEvent = False
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Location = "Optional"

        .ReminderSet = True
        .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = "10"

    End With

    oItem.Save()

    oApp = Nothing
    oNameSpace = Nothing
    oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've added some comments so you know where you can update the code for 'your bits'. Hopefully it's all clear.

The above could be greatly improved, but, it will get you going. However you will need to note, that, the events you're entering are not synced - meaning, let's pretend you wanted to change the subject of the event. You'd have to do this manually for every event you have in the calender. It won't automatically update.

The above is tested quickly, it added the events but there could be bugs etc so please do check it yourself :)

And again, before you try and add 50 entires, do try to add just 1 or 2 first to ensure it does do what you want!

Comment: Thanks Dave.I will test it and let you know. Although in the above code it there a way we can avoid hard coding the holidays, I guess not, just wanted to confirm. May be I can make the changes to code internally. Thanks again.

Comment: Not that I know of @Pegasus21, but, you could update the code easily to only check for [day/month](http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html) and ignore year

Answer (score 1):

Outlook has an inbuilt functionality for this.

Select Schedule Task and click the "Recurrence" button.

In the frame on the right, the second option contains a drop down of "Weekday". So you can directly set a recuring reminder for the 2nd or 3rd Weekday of each month.